# Not able to tap Date of birth field through 'find element by id' in Appium-ruby(Native iOS App) for automation?

Tags: ios, ruby, automation, cucumber, appium-ios

Getting below error in Appium

```
REMOTE] Could not connect to WebKitRemoteDebugger server

info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/81921036-ccb1-4ca3-9b97-319145e345fe/contexts {}
info: [debug] [REMOTE] Getting WebKitRemoteDebugger pageArray
info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":13,"value":{"message":"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: connect ECONNREFUSED)","code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","origValue":"connect ECONNREFUSED"},"sessionId":"81921036-ccb1-4ca3-9b97-319145e345fe"}
info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/81921036-ccb1-4ca3-9b97-319145e345fe/contexts 500 2.415 ms - 293
```

Versions used
 Xcode : 7.2
Appium :1.6

Desired Capabilities:
    require "appium_lib"
        def caps
          {
              caps:{ deviceName: "YIP-25",
                     platformName: "iOS",
                     Fullreset: "false",
                     Noreset: "true",
                     app: (File.join(File.dirname(**FILE**), "app-fs-debug.ipa")),
                     Packagename: "br.com.fs.ensinabyfs",
                     newCommandTimeout: "3600",
                     autoGrantPermissions: "true",
                     appium_lib: { wait: 20,
                                   debug: false,
                     }
              }
          }
        end
        def server_url
          'http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub'
        end
        Appium::Driver.new(caps)   #Pass capabilities for appium inside the driver
        Appium.promote_appium_methods Object #Makes all appium_lib methods accessible from steps
        $driver.start_driver  #Starts appium driver before the tests begin

Please help me out in this?

Comment: Hi, Please update your question with more details like, what code u used to start appium, xml of the element, webdriver version etc..

Comment: @kaushal Rupani - I am starting with 

`$driver.start_driver  #Starts appium driver before the tests begin`

Elemet label : `label: Security_DOBTextFieldId`

Ruby Code : `Then(/^I tap on identifier "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg|
  wait_true { exists { find_element(id: arg).click }}
end`

Comment: What is your iOS version? Also share list of capabilities you are using.

Comment: @kaushalRupani iOS- 9.3.2  and i have updated the capabilities in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Update your xcode to 8.x latest version .
Update your Appium to 1.6.4 latest version .
Update you appium_lib gem version to latest version .

Install appium_doctor

```
npm install -g appium-doctor
appium-doctor --ios
```

This will check the health of your appium ios setup

Then run your tests as XCUITest and not as UIAutomator

Following are capabilities you can use:

You need to use capability

```
caps = {
      :platformName => "iOS",
      :deviceName => "iPhone 6",
      :platformVersion => "9.3",
      :app => app_path,
      :noReset => 'true',
      :newCommandTimeout => "30",
      :automationName => "XCUITest",
      :sendKeyStrategy => 'setValue'
  }
```

Now that done, once appium starts, just try to find your element like normal web element

`driver.find_element(id: 'dob').click`

Hope it helps!!